# Mysql 2 searchs 2 tables join

Tags: mysql, search, join

Is it possible to do two searches on 2 different tables and collect where they overlap, in one query, using JOIN in some way?

Here is the thought process in human terms: (note, I have two tables; profiles & invoices)

- Find all rows from invoice table which have paid column filled with
  "paid"
- Get all the corresponding 'profileid' column numbers
- remove duplicates (or multiple occurances)
- Find all profiles in profiles table with theses id's
- Do further searches on these profiles, such as where firstname LIKE '%$firstname%' etc

Something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT profileid FROM invoicetable WHERE paidcolumn LIKE '%$paid%' INNER JOIN profiletable ON 
invoicetable.profileid=profiletable.id WHERE (profiletable.firstname LIKE '%$firstname%' AND profiletable.email LIKE ........)";
```

I get the feeling I'm almost there...

Or do I have to do it through an array first?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.profileid
FROM invoicetable I
    INNER JOIN profiletable P
        ON I.profileid=P.id
WHERE P.firstname LIKE '%$firstname%'
         AND I.paidcolumn LIKE '%$paid%'
         AND P.email LIKE ........
```

Comment: thanks. seems to get me a bit closer but giving me duplicates. if one person has 2 invoices, his profile is coming up twice, should just be once.

Comment: Can you provide tables scheme and relationship between them? As fast solution you can use `DISTINCT`.